# Node Express Gateway multiple API endpoints

Tags: node.js, api, express, api-gateway

I am trying to create multiple endpoints using Node Express API Gateway and it seems not working. What I would like to do is to have:

localhost:8080/api/v1/patients => localhost:8002/api/v1/patients

localhost:8080/api/v1/doctors => localhost:8003/api/v1/doctors

etc..

```
http:
  port: 8080
apiEndpoints:
  patients:
    host: 'localhost'
    paths: '/api/v1/*'
  doctors:
    host: 'localhost'
    paths: '/api/v1/*'    
serviceEndpoints:
  patients:
    url: 'http://localhost:8003'
  doctors:
    url: 'http://localhost:8002'    
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
pipelines:
  patients:
    apiEndpoints:
      - patients
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
    # - key-auth:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: patients
              changeOrigin: true
  doctors:
    apiEndpoints:
      - doctors
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
    # - key-auth:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: doctors
              changeOrigin: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should not do wildcard, setting the full path works.

```
...
  patients:
    host: localhost
    paths: '/api/v1/patients'
  doctors:
    host: localhost
    paths: '/api/v1/doctors'
...
```